# How to create PhoneGap android project in Mac

Tags: android, cordova

I followed this guide :
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

In `4. Setup New Project` said I should run `./create` command in PhoneGap `bin` folder.

But I don't know where is PhoneGap `bin` folder, because I installed the PhoneGap with `sudo npm install -g phonegap`

Where is `bin` folder of PhoneGap ?

Comment: Why are you creating android project in Mac?

Comment: npm must have install phonegap sdk..go to that location.libs->android->bin

Comment: @ConnectingCode Because I want develop an Android Application, my laptop is MacBook Pro

Comment: @KamleshArya Where is location.libs ? :(

Answer (score 1):

npm will install the latest version of PhoneGap. Please refer to [3.5.0 documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) to get detailed instructions on how to create new project.

Answer (score 1):

@MajAfy - Please check this.

[www.simdroids.com/getting-started-with-phonegap-using-cli/](http://www.simdroids.com/getting-started-with-phonegap-using-cli/)

Step by step tutorial to create and it is explained clearly about the directory structure.